# Why repr of pandas dataframe members is so verbose?

Tags: python, pandas

Try the following:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(range(100))]*100)
>>> df.tail
<bound method NDFrame.tail of     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  ...  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  \
0    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 ...  90  91  92  93  94  95  96   
1    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 ...  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  
...
```

The representation of just a bound method is 127 lines and repeats all data:

```
>>> len(repr(df.tail).split('\n'))
127
```

I have no idea why for instance `repr(df.tail)` contains a copy of the data.  It sounds pointless to me.
If you run the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(range(100))]*100)
count = 0
for i in dir(df):
    s = repr(getattr(df, i))
    count += len(s.split('\n'))
print(count)
```

you will see that the repr of all df members is 53317 lines!

Could anyone explain this to me please?

Comment: df.tail() adding () at the end

Answer (score 0):

With the following options repr of dataframe members do not contain the frame data.

```
>>> pd.options.display.memory_usage = False
>>> pd.options.display.max_info_columns=1
>>> pd.options.display.large_repr = "info"
```